# React Native TextInput showing undefined on android

Tags: react-native

I am using passing function as prop to a component and updating the state of textinput on change.
It is working fine on the web browser and alert the same input written but when I run it on my android device using expo client.
It alerts undefined instead of the actual input.
My piece of code is:

```
//Main Component
const [search, setsearch] = useState('');
const searchinput = (inp) => {
  setsearch(inp.target.value);
  alert(search);
};
<Nav Search={searchinput} inpValue={search} Click={() => searchapi()} />

//Nav Component
<TextInput
  value={props.inpValue}
  onChange={props.Search}
  style={{height: 25, width: 100, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 0}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={props.inpValue}
      onChange={props.Search}
      style={{height: 125, width: 100, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [search, setsearch] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert(search);
  }, [search]);

  const searchinput = (inp) => {
    setsearch(inp.nativeEvent.text);
  };

  return <Nav Search={searchinput} inpValue={search} />;
}
```

Here the current `TextInput` text value is retrieved inside the `onChange` using `inp.nativeEvent.text`.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#onchange

---

I've also added a `useEffect` hook that correctly tracks the current value of the `search` state. With the way you were accessing the `search` state after updating it, you can't be sure that you're actually referring to current value of the `TextInput`